# How to efficiently count the numbers between [start, end] whose prime factors are only 3 or 5?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

In a coding assessment I had this question where the timeout limit was 10s for runtime. The question asked to return the count of numbers that are divisible by only 3 or 5 and not by any other number and I was a bit stumped on how to solve it efficiently.

This is basically what I tried:

```
count = 0
for num in start...end:
   while num % 3 == 0: num /= 3
   while num % 5 == 0: num /= 5
   if num == 1:
      count += 1
```

Comment: Never say "find" when you mean "count", because you can often count things without finding them all, and that can be fantastically faster.

Comment: I don't understand; there are infinite such numbers that can satisfy only being divisible by 3 or 5 even in a range because the ends can be infinitely large and small. Can you provide an example of the size of the bounds?

Comment: How large are start and end?

Comment: Is there a largest end-of-range value you need to consider?

Comment: 1 <= start <= end <= 2*10^9

Comment: Hmm, that's *tiny*. Why is the time limit so large then?

Answer (score 2):

All solutions are of the form `3^x * 5^y`. We will consider the results per value of `y`. We start by finding the value of `y` that is the largest that has valid results, and see which corresponding values of `x` produce the smallest product above `start` and below `end`. The difference between the two values of `x` is then the number of valid results for this value of `y`. Then we decrement `y` and divide the products by 5, and check whether we can bring the products back into the range by increasing the value of `x`. And so on... This requires at most a few dozen calculations even for large ranges.

If you want to keep it simple and stick to integer arithmetic and avoid costly operations like logarithms, you could do something like this:
*(It clocks in comfortably within the time limit for regular integer ranges, but I haven't tried it with big integers.)*

```js
function factors3and5(start, end) {
    var fives = 0;
    var threesMin = 0, threesMax = 0;
    var productMin = 1, productMax = 1;
    var count = 0;

    while (productMax < end) {
        ++fives;
        productMax *= 5;
    }
    productMin = productMax;

    while (fives-- > 0) {
        productMin /= 5;
        productMax /= 5;
        while (productMin <= start) {
            ++threesMin;
            productMin *= 3;
        }
        while (productMax * 3 < end) {
            ++threesMax;
            productMax *= 3;
        }
        count += threesMax - threesMin + 1;
    }
    return count;
}
document.write(factors3and5(12345, 111222333444555)); // 288
```

Comment: factors3and5(3,3) = -1

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for all the values of x and y such that 3<sup>x</sup>5<sup>y</sup> is in the range [start, end] (and calculating 3<sup>x</sup>5<sup>y</sup> for all those pairs).  It's pretty easy to find all the values of x and y that can be solutions, and find all the value of x for a given y with just logs:

- [0, floor(log<sub>5</sub>(end))] is all the possible values of y
- [ceil(log<sub>3</sub>(start / 5<sup>y</sup>)), floor(log<sub>3</sub>(end / 5<sup>y</sup>))] are all the possible values of x for a given y.

So just two nested loops (in whatever language you prefer) over those two bounds will give you all the values.  You can then optimize this by strength-reducing and hoisting operations (for example, 5<sup>y</sup> in the inner loop can be hoisted to be a single multiply in the outer loop.  The upper bound of the outer loop can be tested as 5<sup>y</sup> <= end rather than y <= floor(log<sub>5</sub>(end)))

You might end up with something as simple as

```
for (a = 1; a <= end; a *= 5)
    for (b = a*pow(3, ceil(log(start/a)/log(3))); b <= end; b *= 3)
        printf("%d\n", b);
```

which might be even faster to compute with

```
for (a = 1; a <= end; a *= 5)
    for (b = a; b <= end; b *= 3)
        if (b >= start) printf("%d\n", b);
```

requiring no logs or powers or even divides at all -- and also avoiding possible floating-point rounding issues with the pow+ceil+log stuff that might miss `start` if it should be included in the output.

If you actually just want the count rather than the actual values, replace the `printf` with a `count++`

Answer (score 1):

A bunch of similar solutions, the fastest counts the good numbers among all numbers with 10000 to 20000 digits in less than one second. A version that takes far less memory still does it in a bit over two seconds:

```
start, end = 10**9999, 10**20000  =>  result = 449831572
0.883378 s  187.300 MB  solve4
2.275018 s    0.040 MB  solve5
```

They work by successively dividing the range by 5 until it's empty, and keeping track of the smallest and largest power of 3 in the current range.

Complete results with smaller numbers and all solutions (note: your Ruby-like `start...end` looks like you meant `end` being excluded, so I did that. If you want it included, do `end += 1` as the first thing in the solutions):

```
start, end = 10**3, 10**6  =>  result = 46
0.348141 s    0.000 MB  solve0
0.000022 s    0.000 MB  solve1
0.000029 s    0.001 MB  solve2
0.000017 s    0.000 MB  solve3
0.000040 s    0.001 MB  solve4
0.000013 s    0.000 MB  solve5

start, end = 15**100, 15**200  =>  result = 62421
0.029038 s    0.000 MB  solve1
0.001891 s    0.075 MB  solve2
0.000375 s    0.045 MB  solve3
0.000834 s    0.045 MB  solve4
0.000566 s    0.001 MB  solve5

start, end = 15**100+1, 15**200  =>  result = 62420
0.026116 s    0.000 MB  solve1
0.001787 s    0.075 MB  solve2
0.000882 s    0.045 MB  solve3
0.000972 s    0.045 MB  solve4
0.002052 s    0.001 MB  solve5

start, end = 15**100, 15**200+1  =>  result = 62422
0.034296 s    0.000 MB  solve1
0.000625 s    0.075 MB  solve2
0.001123 s    0.045 MB  solve3
0.001079 s    0.045 MB  solve4
0.000543 s    0.001 MB  solve5

start, end = 10**999, 10**2000  =>  result = 4502601
0.142669 s    3.398 MB  solve2
0.015088 s    2.022 MB  solve3
0.017744 s    2.022 MB  solve4
0.026328 s    0.004 MB  solve5

start, end = 10**9999, 10**20000  =>  result = 449831572
1.026675 s  187.308 MB  solve3
0.883378 s  187.300 MB  solve4
2.275018 s    0.040 MB  solve5
```

The code ([Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=rVdNb-M2EL370lPvAwSFP2I7drxOGyMK4GxzarfoobcgMGiJsulIpCBSyQaL_pJe9tL-qP6azpD6tozdDWrAkE3OcDjvPQ5Hf_2TvJq9kp8__52ZcPLTv999H6YqBiNiDiJOVGog4Wm48VUmDU-BaTvXy-dMynwesyhSvp2Ke70z-I2JZz4Gw7UBzvw9yCzeoq-QYPYcUiZ3vBfwELSKnvlsoA1LzRi4DIarHuDHBgMPZvZfqNCVnK3jsTV9XvYi4iCVQcsfYLHCx8WFB4sTBsvCYFkauJjnHk54HszteMpNlko3RYm9V3GSGQ5MBrk9Zg47pYI8RX0ix_mXcmRQxHQbZXBDtlWCWzRgrWy2baNGHlu49cCGbcxvYVTHhdHfZWe2v6fcLxLGNCXnAQ8gUS-Y55iylJg6PlOV7fY2azcHKoTFFBf4hfPEKuSJhshAk1RIFoRgxNId_VZPzpGMlpZtMvWzNOWYSTmFS5Z4Xh7jSXMu_mDLNK9pI9-VBw-P1ViJdwVnAjfeMZ7Oe8qSBKcGybA5SehRuHI0B9F52dE1hso3tnDed9XI0o2g5uCA34jLwd3wxBlgJK51W_PCYok0wt2DmMwfS9abaQiYHGd8qPkect8jAA5Nz1JfOA6iUzi_iiee8zSGbWZAvwiDZSBVyL2l0sZdjkHJ6BWSSmc1AY1xIbLSme9zrbGioGkgnkXArT62GC3QsH1FzWBcEVXnDoQGHifmtaaYxbFi1pUkOo5fC4l1oQA2bJ6dxRGB6yEiM-8g0a2Ni8Btm6KCSyRgZtNeP4hvpLLmengrk_SxEXHPE4cYlkmYLIcAZ-BzEQm5syxooWTpQimRAz2d-Rd0sXC6CBQIV0NR2ZLvmEGaa6VUG84CUkOgKG47vq7x--6Y3zKRqgjmG8VHlwImTQm0Ifx_JXDzdRK4ebsEuqrZt0igeT86bk_dFRW17xy1hj3hWQ9ZinhoDTGPVfoKzNhTyj8ijpoTs1pho6ETvFvoxvhZyb6pFwTENxLajMi0XhzgkOHN8WQvmJP3inQ3dV40tnQPBepF1lSzfItqGJpbtYwbpA7WsPJsMV0Mj7RD8lpXWBLkjoX7sVUhtkvsLXLhFefshFZYqxNyG-jQz31NP53iWXesdH9CUDgO_M2CCjPp043tGsRx3kSNy0ulKCKF4hyZrkXDtsE3EkWHNH3cM9QJFRXbjOI1tHdaKYpMjy5Wt7uywcQ4y9kslwNJ1W_ew7TxdjdaORRWIdnYPB7mq8cWJVpzjBjW1UddpwvW0bNSSNvWFqB1NbbOaLlqIVvL4txzWibG7CEgVAZ4XBAru9X6GRjnuufPLLI2wyYgks6XB2p7wP-DYQlPlfiqV27gDP6gt4biL_nTa8SgqqQp11lE4w1UOjxQWKa-cI3xclSExT6xFaCNtnq6VEgz6NfT7OMBtDj0wbutdoPD7mez7ytBcJMVzpHmnVQX65Uc1xL4YGtjlWk8tRurYdMNSUyQxNMdNxv7GhZsXJUdDB_mj83lVFJbrWqCLQxh_5NZTa_CP0EDfIrhAub8avXjdIEjH-4AEQinm41kMd9sqkUCHtWTd0sNez2rqP58Nhrh8aTHVb_QVjG3HI3mMzzU9ONyNivm6Zi0bM7nX2NV2pzPO61wE9fX1243aFUtdXlkVLOqzBZo5t6O85fk4mX5Pw)):

```py
from time import perf_counter as time
import tracemalloc as tm

# Naive, test each number in the range
def solve0(start, end):
    count = 0
    for i in range(start, end):
        while not i % 3: i //= 3
        while not i % 5: i //= 5
        count += i == 1
    return count

# Compute and count all good numbers in the range
def solve1(start, end):
    count = 0
    a = 1
    while a < end:
        b = a
        while b < end:
            count += b >= start
            b *= 3
        a *= 5
    return count

# Precompute all needed powers, then go through the powers of 3.
# Keep track of the smallest and largest ok power of 5 for the current power of 3.
def solve2(start, end):
    def powers(base):
        powers = []
        p = 1
        while p <= end:
            powers.append(p)
            p *= base
        return powers
    A = powers(3)
    B = powers(5)
    i = j = len(B)
    count = 0
    for a in A:
        while i and a * B[i-1] >= start:
            i -= 1
        while j and a * B[j-1] >= end:
            j -= 1
        count += j - i
    return count

# Like solve2, but switch roles of 3 and 5, only precompute powers of 3,
# and successively divide the bounds by 5 until the range is empty.
def solve3(start, end):
    A = []
    a = 1
    while a <= end:
        A.append(a)
        a *= 3
    i = j = len(A) - 1
    count = 0
    while end > start:
        while i >= 0 and A[i] >= start:
            i -= 1
        while j >= 0 and A[j] >= end:
            j -= 1
        count += j - i
        start = -(start // -5)  # ceiling division
        end = -(end // -5)
    return count

# Like solve3, but do it all in negative numbers instead of doing ceiling divisions.
def solve4(start, end):
    start = -start
    end = -end
    A = []
    a = -1
    while a >= end:
        A.append(a)
        a *= 3
    i = j = len(A) - 1
    count = 0
    while end < start:
        while i >= 0 and A[i] <= start:
            i -= 1
        while j >= 0 and A[j] <= end:
            j -= 1
        count += j - i
        start //= 5
        end //= 5
    return count

# Like solve4, but takes far less memory at the expense of some speed.
# Don't precompute a *list* of powers of 3, just keep the smallest and largest one and divide back down.
def solve5(start, end):
    start = -start
    end = -end
    a, e = -1, 0
    while (A := a * 3) >= end:
        a = A
        e += 1
    E, A = e, a
    count = 0
    while end < start:
        while e >= 0 and a <= start:
            a //= 3
            e -= 1
        while E >= 0 and A <= end:
            A //= 3
            E -= 1
        count += E - e
        start //= 5
        end //= 5
    return count

funcs = solve0, solve1, solve2, solve3, solve4, solve5

# Correctness, exhaustive test with small numbers
for start in range(1, 500):
    expect = 0
    for end in range(start, 500):
        for f in funcs[1:]:
            assert f(start, end) == expect
        while not end % 3: end //= 3
        while not end % 5: end //= 5
        expect += end == 1

def test(args, funcs):
    start, end = eval(args)
    expect = none = object()
    for f in funcs:

        # Time
        t = time()
        result = f(start, end)
        t = time() - t

        # Correctness
        if expect is none:
            print('start, end =', args, ' =>  result =', result)
            expect = result
        else:
            assert result == expect

        # Memory
        tm.start()
        f(start, end)
        m = tm.get_traced_memory()[1]
        tm.stop()
        
        print(f'{t:.6f} s  {m / 1e6:7.3f} MB ', f.__name__)
        del result
    print()

test('10**3, 10**6', funcs)
test('15**100, 15**200', funcs[1:])
test('15**100+1, 15**200', funcs[1:])
test('15**100, 15**200+1', funcs[1:])
test('10**999, 10**2000', funcs[2:])
test('10**9999, 10**20000', funcs[3:])
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all you do not need to divide at all, you can instead multiply by your factors instead if incrementing and testing divisors... so first "naive approach" would look like this (C++):

```cpp
unsigned int count_factors2_naive(unsigned int xf,unsigned int yf,unsigned int beg,unsigned int end)
    {
    unsigned int n=0,x,xx,y,yy;
    for (x=0,xx=1;xx<=end;x++,xx*=xf)
     for (y=0,yy=xx;yy<=end;y++,yy*=yf)
      if (yy>=beg) n++;
    return n;
    }
```

Where `xf,yf` are your factors `3,5` and `<beg,end>` is the range (inclusive). Beware `10^9` will overflow 32 bit unsigned int as `5*10^9` is already out of 32bit range `(2^32)-1` so you would need to add additional conditions to handle that for example:

```cpp
unsigned int count_factors2_naive(unsigned int xf,unsigned int yf,unsigned int beg,unsigned int end)
    {
    unsigned int n=0,x,xx,y,yy,xx0,yy0;
    for (x=0,xx0=xx=1;(xx<=end)&&(xx0<=xx);x++,xx0=xx,xx*=xf)
     for (y=0,yy0=yy=xx;(yy<=end)&&(yy0<=yy);y++,yy0=yy,yy*=yf)
      if (yy>=beg) n++;
    return n;
    }
```

exploiting that result of multiplication after overflow will be smaller than original value...

Using 32bit integers (32bit C++ App 14+ years old AMD A8-5500 3.2GHz x64 win7 PC):

```
count_factors2_naive(3,5,1000,1000000000);
```

returns `119` and its computed in `~0.001 ms` so unless you go for 64 bits or more its pointless to optimize more as more advanced approaches will be slower on 32bit "small" numbers...

If you need it anyway you can improve by computing start and end power for y using `log`:

```
y0=log(beg/xx,yf);
y1=log(end/xx,yf);
```

and repair `y0` if its off by one due rounding:

```
yy=xx*pow(yf,y0); if (yy<beg) y0++;
```

and now just instead of the `y` `for` loop use simple addition:

```
n+=y1-y0+1;
```

Also using `xf>yf` should be faster (as it needs less iterations). Putting all together:

```cpp
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int log(unsigned int a,unsigned int b)
    {
    unsigned int x;
    for (x=0;a>=b;a/=b) x++;
    return x;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int pow(unsigned int a,unsigned int b)
    {
    unsigned int i,bits=32,d=1;
    for (i=0;i<bits;i++)
        {
        d*=d;
        if ((unsigned int)(b&0x80000000)) d*=a;
        b<<=1;
        }
    return d;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
unsigned int count_factors2(unsigned int xf,unsigned int yf,unsigned int beg,unsigned int end)
    {
    unsigned int n=0,x,xx,y0,y1,yy;
    if (xf<yf){ x=xf; xf=yf; yf=x; }
    for (x=0,xx=1;xx<=end;x++,xx*=xf)
        {
        y0=log(beg/xx,yf);
        y1=log(end/xx,yf);
        yy=xx*pow(yf,y0); if (yy<beg) y0++;
        n+=y1-y0+1;
        }
    return n;
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

using:

```
count_factors2(3,5,1000,1000000000);
```

also returns `119` and its computed in `~0.003 ms` which is slower on 32bit as expected (but should be much faster on big numbers if fast `pow,log` algorithms are used)...